# sudo R CMD javareconf solution not working

Tags: java, r, stdio, rjava

I am trying to run rJava in RStudio but without success:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Using the common solution for rJava issues, 'sudo R CMD javareconf' doesn't work and gives me this ouput:

```
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 11.0.6
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.6.jdk/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.6.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.6.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
clang-7: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
In file included from conftest.c:1:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.6.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h:39:10: fatal error: 
      'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.6.jdk/Contents/Home
Java library path: 
JNI cpp flags    : 
JNI linker flags : 
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

Did anyone come across this error before and knows how to tackle it?

Comment: I see that you're running a linux machine. There are some prerequisites for installing rJava.
Run these commands.
"sudo apt-get install -y default-jre"
"sudo apt-get install -y default-jdk"
"sudo R CMD javareconf"
Then open R as a sudo user and run
'install.packages("rJava")'
Exit RStudio and open again.
For more info visit https://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-rjava-on-ubuntu/

Comment: He's on Mac. You can tell from the `/Library/...`

Comment: `R`, `Java`, and `macOS` are the ingredients for a total mess :) http://www.owsiak.org/r-3-4-rjava-macos-and-even-more-mess/ also, for older version of `R` - http://www.owsiak.org/r-java-rjava-and-macos-adventures/ - in your case it also looks like you don't have `XCode` and `Command Line Tools` installed. You can install `XCode` from `App Store` for free.

Comment: As you are using Java 11 I think this one might be the best option for you: http://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava/

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this with a coworker recently after they upgraded to Catalina. My solution was to install the offending version of JDK again. It looks like your system has confusion between 11.0.6 and 11.0.1.

1. Go to this page: 
   https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase11-5116896.html
2. Download and install 11.0.1
3. sudo R CMD javareconf
4. sudo Rstudio # elevate privs
5. install.packages("rJava")

If that doesn't work, try again from step 2, but with 11.0.6 from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html

Comment: Thanks @Brandon, the 4th line doesn't work for me as Rstudio cmd can't be recognized. Even without it, library(rJava) works now but running other functions that depend on it make RStudio crash as it is still searching somewhere else it seems. I have both installed now, and switch between them by adjusting java_home in .bash_profile. Do you recommend deleting the different versions instead perhaps?

Comment: It might just be `sudo rstudio` lowercase. I'm not on a mac here.

Comment: Does it give you the same error when you run R in the console? (R, then `library(rJava)` at the R repl.

Comment: What did the trick in the end was to show Rstudio where to look as identified by user Rmadillo here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2254

Comment: @ThijsvandenBurg add it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick in the end was to show Rstudio where to look as identified by user Rmadillo here:

[github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2254](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2254)

Just run this each time before using the rJava package.